# Can't get all img tags when scrapping website with BeautifulSoup (BS4)

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get a list of all the `<img>` image tags on a website. Unfortunately, I only get a handful and cannot get the rest despite them existing in the HTML code when I use developer tools. In my code below, I stop getting `img` tags after `TRU`, or about only 10 tags. There are many others.

**Here's my code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

# get list of token IMGs
r = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/view/real-world-assets/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
soup = soup.find('table', {'class':'sc-482c3d57-3 iTyfmj cmc-table'})
soup = soup.find_all('tr')
for s in soup:
    print(s)
    print('************')
```

**Here's what I'm referring to:***

```
************
<tr><td><span class="sc-c0b4ee1-2 bwyOyZ"></span></td><td style="text-align:start"><p class="sc-4984dd93-0 iWSjWE" color="text2" data-sensors-click="true" font-size="14">412</p></td><td style="text-align:start"><div class="sc-aef7b723-0 LCOyB" display="flex"><a class="cmc-link" href="/currencies/truefi-token/"><div class="sc-aef7b723-0 sc-b585f443-0 hqAcrb" data-sensors-click="true"><img alt="TRU logo" class="coin-logo" decoding="async" fetchpriority="low" loading="lazy" src="https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/7725.png"/><div class="sc-aef7b723-0 sc-b585f443-1 dUXsZC hide-ranking-number"><p class="sc-4984dd93-0 kKpPOn" color="text" data-sensors-click="true" font-size="1" font-weight="semibold">TrueFi</p><div class="sc-b585f443-2 SoolS" data-nosnippet="true"><p class="sc-4984dd93-0 iqdbQL coin-item-symbol" color="text3" data-sensors-click="true" font-size="1">TRU</p></div></div></div></a></div></td><td style="text-align:end"><div class="sc-a0353bbc-0 gDrtaY"><a class="cmc-link" href="/currencies/truefi-token/#markets"><span>$0.03894</span></a></div></td><td style="text-align:end"><span class="sc-97d6d2ca-0 bQjSqS"><span class="icon-Caret-down"></span>0.09%</span></td><td style="text-align:end"><span class="sc-97d6d2ca-0 cYiHal"><span class="icon-Caret-up"></span>2.53%</span></td><td style="text-align:end"><span class="sc-97d6d2ca-0 cYiHal"><span class="icon-Caret-up"></span>14.77%</span></td><td style="text-align:end"><p class="sc-4984dd93-0 jZrMxO" color="text" data-sensors-click="true" font-size="1" style="white-space:nowrap"><span class="sc-f8982b1f-0 jYSZLP">$41.55M</span><span class="sc-f8982b1f-1 bOsKfy" data-nosnippet="true">$41,552,664</span></p></td><td style="text-align:end"><div class="sc-aef7b723-0 sc-a0b7a456-0 iHWrYq"><a class="cmc-link" href="/currencies/truefi-token/#markets"><p class="sc-4984dd93-0 jZrMxO font_weight_500" color="text" data-sensors-click="true" font-size="1">$3,402,169</p></a><div data-nosnippet="true"><p class="sc-4984dd93-0 ihZPK" color="text2" data-sensors-click="true" font-size="0">87,376,391 TRU</p></div></div></td><td style="text-align:end"><div class="sc-aef7b723-0 sc-e8f714de-0 cELvic" data-sensors-click="true" style="cursor:pointer"><div class="sc-aef7b723-0 sc-e8f714de-1 hSniWt"><p class="sc-4984dd93-0 WfVLk" color="text" data-sensors-click="true" font-size="1" font-weight="medium">1,067,178,474 TRU</p></div><div class="sc-4ff2400b-0 hKysZR" data-sensors-click="true" width="160"><div class="sc-4ff2400b-1 ldlqLF" width="118"></div></div></div></td><td style="text-align:end"><a class="cmc-link" href="/currencies/truefi-token/?period=7d"><img alt="truefi-token-7d-price-graph" class="sc-482c3d57-0 gsWGOt isUp" loading="lazy" src="https://s3.coinmarketcap.com/generated/sparklines/web/7d/2781/7725.svg"/></a></td></tr>
************
<tr class="sc-428ddaf3-0 bKFMfg"><td><span></span></td><td><span></span></td><td><a class="cmc-link" href="/currencies/propy/"><span class="circle"></span><span>Propy</span><span class="crypto-symbol">PRO</span></a></td><td><span>$<!-- -->0.33</span></td><td><span></span></td></tr>
************
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is stored inside `<script>` variable in Json form, so use `json` module to parse it:

```py
import json

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/view/real-world-assets/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

data = json.loads(soup.select_one("#__NEXT_DATA__").text)
data = json.loads(data["props"]["initialState"])

columns = data["cryptocurrency"]["listingLatest"]["data"][0]["keysArr"]
values = data["cryptocurrency"]["listingLatest"]["data"][1:]

df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=columns + ["tmp"])
df["img_url"] = df["id"].apply(
    lambda x: "https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/{}.png".format(x)
)

# to print all data:
# print(df)

# print only subset of data:
print(df[["name", "id", "img_url"]])
```

Prints:

```
                    name     id                                                        img_url
0                  Maker   1518   https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/1518.png
1              Synthetix   2586   https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/2586.png
2         Ribbon Finance  12387  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/12387.png
3         Reserve Rights   3964   https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/3964.png
4             Centrifuge   6748   https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/6748.png
5               Polymath   2496   https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/2496.png
6               Polymesh  20362  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/20362.png
7             Creditcoin   5198   https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/5198.png
8                  Bytom   1866   https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/1866.png
9                 TrueFi   7725   https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/7725.png
10                 Propy   1974   https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/1974.png
11                 Maple   9417   https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/9417.png
12               Opulous  10409  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/10409.png
13        Boson Protocol   8827   https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/8827.png
14             Goldfinch  13967  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/13967.png
15             Clearpool  12573  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/12573.png
16                ELYSIA   5382   https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/5382.png
17             Landshare  11245  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/11245.png
18             Polytrade  10465  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/10465.png
19         Swarm Markets  11821  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/11821.png
20        Realio Network   4166   https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/4166.png
21          Stobox Token   7245   https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/7245.png
22      Horizon Protocol   9237   https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/9237.png
23            LABS Group   8813   https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/8813.png
24            UBXS Token  17242  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/17242.png
25            Acquire.Fi  20154  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/20154.png
26                  Ekta  11516  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/11516.png
27              Defactor  13255  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/13255.png
28           AssetMantle  19686  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/19686.png
29               Credefi  13272  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/13272.png
30     Blocksquare Token   3035   https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/3035.png
31                  LEOX  21926  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/21926.png
32      Crafting Finance  16100  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/16100.png
33                 STIMA  19867  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/19867.png
34          NAOS Finance   9504   https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/9504.png
35              KlimaDAO  12873  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/12873.png
36       Domani Protocol   8691   https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/8691.png
37                Comdex  14713  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/14713.png
38        Poison Finance  23125  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/23125.png
39             Theopetra  23932  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/23932.png
40               IX Swap  11620  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/11620.png
41               CitaDAO  17515  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/17515.png
42      Curio Governance   8131   https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/8131.png
43              HomeCoin  10342  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/10342.png
44                  Ondo  21159  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/21159.png
45       Bluejay Finance  22515  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/22515.png
46  OpenEden TBILL Vault  25158  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/25158.png
47           Staked USDT  27793  https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/27793.png
```